# How to get base secure url without index.php

Tags: magento-1.7, script, secure, base-url

I want to to get `base-secure-url` without `index.php`.

I enabled `index.php` for some reason. Now I have a PHP file at Magento root directory, and I want to call Magento secure pages from this PHP file.

**Note: i have multi stores in my site**

Please provide more ideas on this.

Comment: can you tell me the path for this? Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL); sorry. I am new to magento

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/132405)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/132405)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL);
```

I mention this because no one else has, but I prefer using [`Mage::getUrl`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) or `Mage::getBaseUrl`.  Both of those automatically detect if the page is already secure when you do not specify it.

Comment: is it working  on multi store with different domain name

Comment: You can specify a store with the second parameter of `getStoreConfig`.  It accepts an ID, a code (as set in admin) or a `Mage_Core_Model_Store` object, just use whatever you have available in your code.

Comment: Replacing 'Mage::getUrl' with 'Mage::getBaseUrl' did the trick for me

Answer (score 11):

as @Aphroz said, you can use

```
Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true );
```

in order to retrieve secure base url. This returns secure url because we have specified it through second parameter `true`. Here first parameter is specified as `Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB`. This means the method returns value correspond to this system configuration field `web/secure/base_url`. This field is the value that we specify at

```
 System  >  Configuration  > Web  >  Secure url
```

so if this field is not using `index.php` there along with the base url, then the method will not give index.php along with the url. If it holds `index.php`, then it will return the same. So to ensure index.php is not there you can use `str_replace` function.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is a bug in Magento? The system should know when I am on a secure URL and then default all its Mage::getBaseUrl() to secure.

Answer (score 5):

Below URL Access list

### Get URLs in CMS pages or static blocks

1. Base URL:

   ```
   {{base url=''}}
   ```
2. Store URL:

   ```
   {{store url='test.html'}}
   ```

   also only store URL

   ```
   {{store url=""}}
   ```
3. Media URL:

   only get media URL

   ```
   {{media url=''}}
   ```

   if you get some folder path

   ```
   {{media url='imagefolder/imagename.jpg'}}
   ```
4. Skin URL:

   ```
   {skin url='images/imagename.jpg'}}
   ```

   only get skin URL

   ```
   {skin url=''}}
   ```

### Get URLs in PHP files (incl. templates/PHTML)

1. Get Base Url  in magento:

   ```
   $baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
   ```

   Get Base Url without index.php

   ```
   Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); 

   // output: http://example.com/
   ```
2. Current Url

   ```
   $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
   ```

   or

   ```
   $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (!in_array(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName(), array('cms_index_noRoute', 'cms_index_defaultNoRoute'))) 
   {
       $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
   }
   ```
3. Skin URL:

   ```
   $skinUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);
   ```

   Unsecure Skin URL:

   ```
   $skinUrl = $this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');
   ```

   Secure Skin URL:

   ```
   $this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.gif', array('_secure'=>true));
   ```
4. Media URL

   ```
   $mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
   ```

   or

   ```
   $mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media');
   ```
5. Get Js URL:

   ```
   $jsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);
   ```

   or

   ```
   $jsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('js');
   ```
6. get store URL:

   ```
   $storeUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
   ```
7. Get Home URL:

   ```
   $homeUrl= Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();
   ```
8. Get Directory paths

   ```
   Mage::getBaseDir('design') // Get design directory path
   Mage::getBaseDir('code')   // Gives code directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('lib')    // Gives lib directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('skin')   // Gives skin directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('var')    // Gives var directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('cache')  // Gives cache directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('log')    // Gives log directory file path
   ```
9. Create module URL:

   ```
   Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action');
   ```

[Get More details about get URLs](https://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Store.html)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('link',true);
```

Short and sweet.

Comment: That's the most solid approach, as it'll include any store_code to url, if that's the case

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use this?

```
str_replace('index.php','whatever.php',Mage::getBaseUrl('web', true));
```

Comment: Dude,it is not proper way....

Comment: Then Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ) as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002254/magento-1-7-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: it not  give result when i used secure url

Comment: Not Sure, But .htaccess file can be helpful